# Pair Sony DualShock 4 v2 with Sony Android TV

Tags: android-tv, game-controllers

I am trying to pair a Sony Dualshock 4 controller (CUH-ZCT2E) with my 2015 Sony Bravia Android TV (KDL-55W808C).

The TV has a DUALSHOCK™4 settings menu, through which one should supposedly be able to pair a Dualshock 4 controller with the TV. The on screen instructions says "press and hold the share and PS-buttons until a white light starts flashing on the controller". The white light starts flashing, but the TV is unable to locate the controller.

Then I found [this](https://sony-eur-eu-en-web--eur.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/134686) page listing many Sony Android TVs from 2014 to 2016, including mine, as not supporting the new Dualshock 4 controller (CUH-ZCT2E). Only the older Dualshock 4 controller (CUH-ZCT1E) is supported.

Surely this must be a software limitation which Sony should be able to resolve through an OTA update?
Are there any known workarounds?
Would the [sixaxis controller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dancingpixelstudios.sixaxiscontroller) app help me to pair the controllers, and would I require root for that?
Any known hints of if/when Sony is going to add support for the new 2016 Dualshock 4 to their Android TV sets?

Edit 2016-12-08: Sony Nordic customer support didn't have information about if Sony will add support for Dualshock 4 v2.

Update 2016-12-10:
I just found out [online](http://sony-eur-eu-sv-web--eur.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/138463) that the rollout of Marshmallow to the 2015 (and the spring 2016) TV Sets has begun.

Update 2017-04-25:
The Marshmallow rollout which was halted and postponed by Sony is now officially available as USB download for Nordic customers ([link in Swedish](http://sony-eur-eu-sv-web--eur.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/138463)). After upgrading to Marshmallow I'm still not able to pair through the Dualshock™4 settings menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to pair Dualshock 4 v2 controllers on a Sony 2015 Android TV. I have had no success when trying to pair through the TVs Dualshock 4 settings menu, but I successfully paired three controllers (simultaneously) using the Bluetooth settings menu:

1. If you have a PlayStation - start by unplugging your PlayStation's power cord, since I've noticed that the controllers otherwise sometimes pair with the PlayStation instead of the TV
2. Press the home button on your TVs remote and go to settings.
3. Go to bluetooth settings.

[image: Bluetooth settings]

4. Go to device list

[image: Device list]

5. Add accessory

[image: Add accessory]

[image: Searching for accessories]

6. **Now press and hold the share button on your controller. While still holding the share button - press and hold the PS button on your controller.** Your controller's light should, after a couple of seconds, start to flash in a pattern of two short blinks followed by a pause repeatedly. Soon your tv should identify the controller as "Unknown"

[image: unknown]

7. Press the "select" button on your TVs remote control (the center button of your remote) to start pairing. The TV will identify the controller as "Wireless controller"

[image: wireless controller]

8. The controllers light will turn solid white when pairing is complete.
9. You should now be able to control your tv using the Dualshock 4 v2 controller.
10. If you want to use the controller(s) with PlayStation again, you will need to pair the controller(s) to the Playstation using an USB cable.

While running Android Lollipop I was able to control the TV's menus, play games downloaded through Google Play Store and use the controllers in emulators.
**After upgrading to Marshmallow I'm still able to control the TV, but the experience is now pretty much ruined by heavy input lag starting about 30 seconds after pairing. I still hope to find a solution for this.**

Comment: I just upgraded my TV but I don't have a controller to test if Marshmallow supports it. I am quite interested about the subject because I want to order a v2 controller but not if it doesn't work with the TV (XD85).

Comment: I upgraded manually via USB. Quite pleased.

Comment: @sorin: I've upgraded to Marshmallow. Pairing still works the same as Lollipop BUT I get input latency about 30 seconds after pairing which ruins the experience. There was no noticeable latency while running Lollipop. Right now I wouldn't recommend you to buy a controller.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on my sony bravio with android 6.0 : not even lags but nothing : the controllers light do turn solid blue and the light disappears, and no control after this.

Comment: I obvisouly did, yes. In fact I followed exactly what you preconize in your answer.

Comment: @ujsgeyrr1f0... Sorry to hear that. Did your controller's light flash in white during step 6? Did your TV identify your controller as "wireless controller"? Did you remember to push the "select" button on your TV's remote? After which step did your controller's light turn solid blue? Please be more specific on what works and what doesn't.

Comment: It did yes. Finally it worked. Honestly, every time I strictly followed your step. I suspect simply that the pad wasn't enough charged, but not sure.

Comment: Just paired a CUH-ZCT2U to X850D running Android 7.0 via Bluetooth settings. Works flawlessly with no noticeable lag.

Comment: @dragon:  Thank you for your input! This question and answer is rather dated now. I noticed that in Nougat the Dualshock 4 menu option is gone on my TV. The settings menu looks different, and there is just the bluetooth option now. Glad to hear that you don't experience any lag after pairing. I haven't had the time (or will) to pair to my TV for a while, so I don't know if I would still experience lag. I will test it in a few days and update the answer.